# Json en app inventor

Tags: json, appinventor

que tal. Tengo una pregunta.
Estoy haciendo una app que se conecta mediante un hosting gratuito. Es necesario utilizar un json para poder realizar un abm (de lo que sea) y ver listados en app inventor?

Comment: por ejemplo para mandar los datos de un usuario, o no es necesario?

Comment: si es para almacenar en una base de datos po ej, aun no entiendo muy bien como funciona el json. Pero para hacer esta app me recomendaron mandar un json con la informacion y recibirlo en un php que hace todo

Comment: ahh esta bien, entonces ese json solo me serviria para guardar la informacion?